# How To Upload Laravel Project To shared Hosting without problems

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

i work with laravel 5.2, i have built a small app i just want to upload it to shared hosting
i tried with 000webhost and byethost and i got problems like

```
Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7
```

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.(in two lines without explanation the problem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is in the database engine of the free shared hosting

for example in 000webhost:

edit `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    //.......
    'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,]
],
```

Comment: Problem Solved, Thank You So Much